# How to return to Index of Controller after delete method invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i like to return to Index after the delete is done, but in the Index i have list of categories that return some Id. So the question is how to return in Index with the CategoryId?

Here is the Index:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Id")] int categoryId)
    {
        var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);
        if (category != null)
        {
            return View(category);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
```

And Delete:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var entry = _db.Entries.Single(r => r.Id == id);

        _db.Entries.Remove(entry);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Index` method parameter is `categoryId` so

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { categoryId = entry.FK_CategoryId});`
```

Note, you dont need the `[Bind(Prefix = "Id")]`

```
public ActionResult Index(int categoryId)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've resolved the problem, i didn't remove the `[Bind(Prefix = "Id")], just changed the logic little, because i was wrong.

Comment: I don't think your understanding `[Bind(Prefix..` Its used in POST methods for complex properties. [This article](http://www.brainthud.com/cards/5218/19788/what-is-the-bindattribute-in-the-context-of-aspnet-mvc-and-how-is-it-used) might help

Comment: Yes, you are right, i'm beginner and i'm still learning. Thank you for the article.

Comment: Also in you edited question, you now use just use `return RedirectToAction("Index");` You have not passed a value to the parameter `categoryId` so `var category = _db.Categories.Find(categoryId);` makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

I've found solution, the Delete method now looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Entry entry = _db.Entries.Single(r => r.Id == id);
        if (entry == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entry);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Restaurant/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var entryToDelete = _db.Entries.Single(r => r.Id == id);

        _db.Entries.Remove(entryToDelete);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index",new { id =  entryToDelete.CategoryId });
    }
```